# Deploy new war in tomcat with magnolia cms

Tags: java, tomcat, indexing, jackrabbit, magnolia

in my authoring instance there is my war with magnolia instance and my jcr is in another server on mysql.

I need to deploy a new war but all the content lose the correct indexing (especially the assets)  and even if the DB is never changed most of indexes are losts.

How can i deploy a new war without lose not a single content?

Thank you in advance for the replies.

Magnolia version :  5.5 Community edition
Tomcat version : 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your configuration. Most likely you are still using default location for your repo index and big files that points to within the exploded war file. This is meant only for development only and should not be used for persistent data.

Check [official documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Configuration+management) for more information.

In particular `magnolia.repositories.home` property.